# como especificar la ruta de una .dll en c++ para importalo en c#

Tags: c#, c++

```
[DllImport("Cannabis.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
internal static extern void Entrenado_Casificador_SVM(string imagePath);
```

por ejemplo: que ruta tiene Cannabis.dll ? como cambiarla?

Comment: Has probado a poner la ruta en el `DllImport`? `[DllImport("c:\carpeta\Cannabis.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`?

Comment: ¿qué hace esa `dll`? :O

Comment: esta dll tiene varias funciones pero son internas de mi trabajo, pero no no he probado ponerle la ruta ahi mismo, el problema es que en otro lado esta asi mismo y lo coge de una direccion q esta en c:/ y no se donde es q tiene especificado eso

Comment: A priori, si no pones nada, buscará en el directorio en el que esté la aplicacion ejecutandose

Answer (score 0):

Hola te comento cómo se realiza la búsqueda del ensamblado en un `DllImport`.

1. El directorio desde el cual la aplicación se ha cargado.
2. El directorio de sistema. Se usa la función `GetSystemDirectory`
   para recuperar el path de este directorio.
3. El directorio de Windows.  Se usa la función `GetWindowsDirectory`
   para recuperar el path de este directorio.
4. El directorio actual.
5. Los directorios que se indican en la variable de entorno `PATH`.